# Create new column with a list of max frequency values for each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max, frequency

Given this Dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5],[2,2,2,2,8,8,8,8,6,6]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5
1  2  2  2  2  8  8  8  8  6  6
```

I created 2 news columns which give for each row the **max_freq** and the **max_freq_value**:

```
df2["max_freq_val"] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.mode().agg(list), axis=1)
df2["max_freq"] = df2.loc[:, df2.columns != "max_freq_val"].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().max(), axis=1)

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J max_freq_val  max_freq
0  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5          [3]         6
1  2  2  2  2  8  8  8  8  6  6       [2, 8]         4
```

**EDIT**: I've edited my code inspired by the answer given by **@rhug123**.

Thanks to all of you for your answers.

Comment: Could you elaborate why `df2["max_freq_value"].iloc[1]` should return `[2, 8]`? You're selecting the column `max_freq_value` and then select the item with index 1, which is 8.

Comment: Because for the second row, 2 and 8 both appear 4x -> the max frequency of that row.

Comment: You'll likely want to use the max value with a boolean filter on the value counts histogram. Then, use `tolist()` to get the list. This will result in a one element list if there is a single maximum, and an N element list if there are N max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses `mode()`

```
df2.assign(max_freq=pd.Series(df2.mode(axis=1).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)),
max_freq_value = df2.eq(df2.mode(axis=1)[0].squeeze(),axis=0).sum(axis=1))
```

or

```
df2.assign(freq = df2.eq((s := df2.mode(axis=1).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)).str[0],axis=0).sum(axis=1),val = s)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `stack` then adjust the freq with `agg` put the multiple into the `list`

```
s = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
s = s[s.eq(s.max(level=0),level=0)].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg(val= ('level_1',list),fre=(0,'first'))
df2 = df2.join(s)
df2
Out[156]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J     val  fre
0  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5     [3]    6
1  2  2  2  2  8  8  8  8  6  6  [2, 8]    4
```

Comment: I thought maybe mask and cumsum but this also works a little more flexible too

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this function:

```
def give_back_maximums(a = [2,2,2,2,8,8,8,8,6,6]):
    values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    return values[counts >= counts.max()].tolist()
```

The order of the below could affect the result

```
df2["max_freq_value"] =  df2.apply(lambda x: give_back_maximums(x), axis=1)
df2["max_freq"] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().max(), axis=1)
print(df2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J max_freq_value  max_freq
0  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5            [3]         6
1  2  2  2  2  8  8  8  8  6  6         [2, 8]         4
```

Hope it helps : )